# Ajaxcontroltoolkit 15.1.2 Tabcontainer problems

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I've just upgraded a legacy web application from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5. The application extensively used the `AjaxControlToolkit`. Since a new version is available from *May 2015*, I also upgrade it.

I received several errors so I tried to create an empty project from scratch, adding the `AjaxControlToolkit` through Nuget, and it seems the problem is caused by the `TabContainer` control.

I receive the errors shown in the images below:

[image: First]

> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

[image: Second]

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.

Obviously after those error there's no TabContainer in the page.

**The strange thing is that it happens just in Internet Explorer 9+. It works like a charm in Firefox and Chrome**.

The application is nearly empty, here's the relevant code from the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tc" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tp1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Header
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            Content
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you **have** to use *Bundling* to get it work.

In the project mentioned in the question I have added the AjaxControlToolkit 15.1.2 reference using *nuget*.

To solve the problem I have enabled bundling as explained on [CodePlex](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20bundling%20and%20CDN):

1. Add the reference to `AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources` using *nuget*
2. Change the `ScriptManager` to the following:

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
       <Scripts>
           <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle" />
       </Scripts>
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   ```
3. Add the following to the `<head>` element:

   ```
   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
       <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Bundle") %>
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
   ```
4. Be sure you have this in the `web.config`:

   ```
   <ajaxControlToolkit useStaticResources="true" renderStyleLinks="false" />
   ```

Comment: Is there a specific spot in web.config to place the ajaxcontroltoolkit tag?