# AJAX TabContainer not showing up in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I'm using AJAX Control Toolkit v15.1, asp.net v4.5.1 vs.net 2012 VB code.  Everything is up-to-date.
I'm using the tabcontainer tool from the AJAX toolkit.  And when I run my web app in localhost mode, everything works fine in Chrome and IE.

I publish my code to my IIS web server & view it in Chrome.  Runs great!  Very happy!  But I must test it in IE so I fire up IE 11. 
When IE 11 launches only the top part of my web app loads.  The bottom 75%, which houses the tabcontainer and 11 tabs, does not show up.

I've been reading about changing **asp:Scriptmanager**
 to **ajaxToolkit:toolkitScriptManager** *(which doesn't work by the way.  It doesn't recognize that tag at all.  Immediately throws an error!  I think that may have been a fix 4+ years ago because that's when that fix was posted but does not apply today.)*

Here is my code on what I think would be of value in troubleshooting:
(in my .aspx file)

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1"  %>
```

The beginning of my tabcontainer code:

```
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" runat="server" Width="1723px" Height="568px" AutoPostBack="true" ActiveTabIndex="7">
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="BackupSchedule" runat="server" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Backup Job Schedule" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
```

I'd rather not force people to use Chrome.  That's the easy way out.  I'd rather fix this and not have to worry about it.

Comment: have you tried change the ajaxToolkit:toolkitScriptManager by cc1:Toolkitscriptmanager?, also look at the browser JS console (F12) and search for an error or message

Comment: 1.  I tried prefixing the Register Assembly and the namespace with cc1 and all error broke loose.  I haven't tried to put it in both yet.  Will try that.
2.  Didn't think about the JS console (F12).  Ran that & found this:
if (e) throw e;
Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: type

Unfortunately I didn't do any coding in there.  That was done on the backend.  I'll have to dig into that.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue, Below code worked for me. I got this answer from Forums.asp.net
Try Below setting in web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Changed it to:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I download the Ajax control toolkits V15.1.2 and design a webform with  TabContainer to show something.
When I use IE 11 to view my page the tab didn't show.But When I use Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.130) to view the same page , the tab "show up".
I look for another discussion about TabContainer on stackoverflow in
[Ajaxcontroltoolkit 15.1.2 Tabcontainer problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348100/ajaxcontroltoolkit-15-1-2-tabcontainer-problems) post.
**It soloved my problem!!** 
 Now I can use IE 11 the view my page with tab show up.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is an old thread. I was having the same issues and found that going into IE11 and amending the compatibility View Setting adding the current website ticking both the  Display Intranet Site in Compatibility View and Use Microsoft compatibility list. Closing the setting then reopening and un-ticking then removing the website from the list will bring up the tabs in the same way Chrome and FF does.

Hope this helps?